# JPA: exception obtaining an entity that references another

Tags: java, spring, exception, jpa

I am writing a simple application using Spring and JPA. I have 2 entities: User and Role, with a relation of N..1.

Whenever I try to get any of this entities from the database, I get an exception (It's shown below). Said exception is thrown when one entity tries to get the other entity through its foreign key.

For example, when I ask for a Role, all its attributes are obtained correctly, excepting userCollection (the group of users assigned to that role).

The exception is always thrown, no matter which method I use to ask the entity (.find(pk), .createNamedQuery(), .createQuery(), ...).

Following is the code. I have skipped the non relevant parts:

User entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
        private String id;

        @JoinColumn(name = "rol", referencedColumnName = "id")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Role rol;

        ...
```

Role entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "roles")
    public class Role implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "rol", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Collection userCollection;

        ...
```

The exception thrown when I try to obtain a role:

```
    Exception [EclipseLink-6094] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
    Exception Description: The parameter name [id] in the query's selection criteria does not match any parameter name defined in the query.
    Query: ReadAllQuery(name="userCollection" referenceClass=User sql="SELECT ID, EMAIL, NAME, rol FROM users WHERE (rol = ?)")
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.parameterNameMismatch(QueryException.java:1031)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ParameterExpression.getValue(ParameterExpression.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.translate(DatabaseCall.java:918)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2537)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2496)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:958)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:432)
        ...
```

I tried to remove the userCollection from the Role entity. If I try to get a role it works just fine, but if I try to find an user, I get the following exception:

```
    org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        ...
```

I don't know how to solve this issue. I've spent a lot of time. Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't indicate your table layout, which makes answering your question a guessing game.

To begin, I would avoid using `@Basic` on the ID column in `User`. `@Size` is ok, but you might want to match that in JPA as well. See below (the `nullable=false` and `unique=true` attributes are redundant with the `@Id` annotation):

```
@Id
@Column(length=50, nullable=false, unique=true)
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
private String id;
```

If the ID is basically a user name, this is a bad idea. Things can get tricky down the road if the user wants to change his user name. Additionally, foreign key references to the `users` table require 50 bytes instead of 4 (it's a bit more complex than that, but you get the idea). I'd add a regular `Integer` ID and a separate `userName` field. The user never needs to see the ID.

Similar treatment should be given to `Role.name`:

```
@Column(length=50, nullable=false, unique=true)
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
private String name;
```

Second, it looks like a user can have only one role? Seriously? Anyway, if that's the case the `referencedColumnName` attribute is not needed, since the ID column in `roles` uses the default name:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "rol")
private Role rol;
```

Having foreign key column named "rol" instead of "role_id" is not a good idea. I'd use the default (just drop the `@JoinColumn` stuff).

If you intended that users could have more than one role, that requires a join table (you can omit the `@JoinTable` stuff if you want to use the defaults):

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "user_roles",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
)
private List<Role> roles;
```

Third, it's hard to see the usefulness of having the list of users in `Role`. I'd remove it entirely. Instead use something like `user.getRoles.contains(SomeRole)` to see if a user has a certain role.

Finally, looking at your code, there are a couple of things that I should clear up:

- In the "column" annotations (`@Column`, `@JoinColumn`, etc), the `name` and `referencedColumnName` attributes allow you to specify the actual column names. They do not refer to field names in your classes.